# Getting an error Argument type 'Uint8List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to upload my image in firebase storage and got the error The argument type 'Uint8List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'. I am a beginner. Here is my code, please help me resolving this issue.

```
Future<String> uploadImageToStorage(
      Uint8List image, String productUid) async {
    Reference storageRef = storage.ref().child('products').child(productUid);
    UploadTask uploadFile = storageRef.putFile(image);
    TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadFile;
    Future<String> imageUrl = taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    return imageUrl;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the putFile() to putData() and pass the image. Here is an updated code, let me know if this works for you.

```
Future<String> uploadImageToStorage(
      Uint8List image, String productUid) async {
    Reference storageRef = storage.ref().child('products').child(productUid);
    UploadTask uploadFile = storageRef.putData(image);
    TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadFile;
    Future<String> imageUrl = taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    return imageUrl;
  }
```